# How to upload files using FTP server and django rest api....How to do that?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-ftpserver

am new to django...please be patient if it is basic thing..till i could't acheive this.. I am developing one django rest api for uploading files(ex.image,videos)using FTP server. I thought of use django ftp server library..but am not sure how to connect the FTP server(am using winscp)with django server..